# How to pass a shell command into Python script

Tags: python-3.x, linux, terminal, echo

Hello I would like to pass a shell command in the linux terminal to variable into Python script :

Here is the command in linux :

```
echo "azerty"
```

My python script would be a very simple script that print the result. The name of the script is test.py

In my terminal I would use :

```
echo "azerty" | ./test.py
```

and It would return :

```
azerty
```

Maybe you can hel. Thanks

Comment: do you understand what `|` does? What have you searched?

Comment: yes, first print echo in terminal then run the script Python

Comment: I would like to print the output of the terminal through a Python script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform `some_command | other_command` in any POSIX shell, what it actually does is that it redirects the standard output (called stdout) of `some_command` to the standard input (called stdin) of `other_command`. In python you can access the standard input using the `sys` module.

From the [official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) about `sys.stdin` :

> These streams are regular text files like those returned by the open() function.

Reading the standard input in python is as simple as that :

```py
import sys
content = sys.stdin.read()
print(content)
```